# Javascript to return time in format 00.00.00 from 0.0.0

Tags: javascript, date, format

I need to adapt a code in javascript to return the time in 00.00.00 format actually it return format like 0.0.0

Example time generated:
0.5.11

I need this format:
00.05.11 (5 minutes and 11 seconds after midnight)

This is my javascript code

```
(new Date().getHours()+"." + new Date().getMinutes() + "." + new Date().getSeconds())
```

I need to integrate this javascript in macro software i can not load any external library or files, only javascript can be used.

Thanks

Comment: What precisely do you mean by "macro software"?

Comment: I use Kantu it is a free solution based of Selenium IDE and with storeeval can store javascript in variable to integrate in macro. I can add javascript in Kantu to return some function. The code i posted working well in Kantu selenium IDE but not have prefered format, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try something like this, checking if `hours`, `minutes`, or `seconds` are lower than `10` and adding a leading zero in that case:

```js
let cDate = new Date();
let fmtDate = [cDate.getHours(), cDate.getMinutes(), cDate.getSeconds()]
    .map(x => x < 10 ? "0" + x : x)
    .join(".");

console.log(fmtDate)
```

```css
.as-console {background-color:black !important; color:lime;}
.as-console-wrapper {max-height:100% !important; top:0;}
```

Alternatively, you can try this one:

```js
let d = new Date();
let h = d.getHours();
h = h < 10 ? "0" + h : h;
let m = d.getMinutes();
m = m < 10 ? "0" + m : m;
let s = d.getSeconds();
s = s < 10 ? "0" + s : s;

let fmtDate = h + "." + m + "." + s;
console.log(fmtDate)
```

```css
.as-console {background-color:black !important; color:lime;}
.as-console-wrapper {max-height:100% !important; top:0;}
```

Comment: When adding in macro software give undefined function it is not javascript pure, the code i posted working but have a wrong format

Comment: @newuserkantu Please, check the alternative example.

Comment: I use Kantu it's a free solution based on selenium IDE and support javascript with storeeval function to store in variable the javascript code. I need a solution to integrate in kantu the code to save the correct time in prefered format, thanks

Comment: @newuserkantu For what I can see [here](https://a9t9.com/kantu/docs/selenium-ide/storeeval) all you will need is to put all the code in one line like this: `let d = new Date(); let h = d.getHours(); h = h < 10 ? "0" + h : h; let m = d.getMinutes(); m = m < 10 ? "0" + m : m; let s = d.getSeconds(); s = s < 10 ? "0" + s : s; h + "." + m + "." + s;` where the last sentence is the evaluated output.

Comment: I tryed like your message and working like a charms, i accept your answer, thanks

Answer (score 2):

You could take the `ISO` string and replace unwanted characters.

```js
console.log(new Date().toISOString().slice(11, 19).replace(/:/g, '.'))
```

Comment: When adding in macro software give undefined function it is not javascript pure, the code i posted working but have a wrong format